# How to analyze a sentence when analyzer is given inside a property of mapping - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, sense, elasticsearch-mapping

here is a simple question:

Normally when i give the analyzer outside of the mapping i query the sentence like:

```
POST three_in_one_index4/_analyze
{
    "analyzer": "english_lower",
    "text": "<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>"    
}
```

Now i give the analyzer inside of the mapping like:

```
"mappings": {
    "column": {
      "properties": {
        "article1": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "english_lower"
        },
        "article2": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "latin_lower"
        },
        "article3": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "latinstem_and_englishlower"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So now how should the analyzing be like?

I'm pretty sure that below is not working as what i mean to do.

```
POST three_in_one_index4/_analyze
{
    "analyzer": "english_lower",
    "text": "<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>"    
}
```

Comment: _analyze is used to know exactly how is going to work the analyzer. ES is going to apply the analyzer that you specify in the mapping to the corresponding property in the Json that you are going to index. I don't understand exactly what do you want to do.

Comment: as far as i get from your comment specifying analyzer inside the mapping does not change the way to /_analyze that. okay if es would understand from what i did it is ok for me, thanks. @angelcervera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to analyze the tokens based on the analyzer for a field as defined in your mapping, then you can do it like :

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/three_in_one_index4/_analyze' -d '
{
  "field" : "article1",
  "text" : "<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>"
}'
```

> Will cause the analysis to happen based on the analyzer configured in
>   the mapping for `article1` (and if not, the default index analyzer).

Comment: The effect of this approach is the same that specify the analyser, plus the risk that if you have a typo in the field name is going to apply the default analyser and could be confusing. IMO If you want test an analyser, is better your first approach. This option is good to check the mapping.